ssh login to KVM guest created with cloud-init fails with 'Permission denied (publickey).'
My cloud-init user-data.yaml contains the id_rsa.pub from my desktop system.
user-data.yaml looks like this:
#cloud-config
users:
  - name: bob
    ssh_authorized_keys:
      - ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDXpi229MbQCjmNluCXf2aPHKJTAzkZG6j9m8gsLeGE+yvBRDGurkwmZa/rZ4U7+Xox0eX5GDcCeFbPdRphhNq323f34t5seufwiueri4uri73rd0azK7CnI/nDL5gO2rLRskjsrrhWuQTPu/geYTayuYl/XVdzotoQz+hyWf1Gt1hCBievFnUtQstGlG9JHfPdfQkdIGAwxoaGNjyoeSUeNlWL1Vb9BN+nclxdEHmwB4xv8FsGl434/Wj+GNGar/dIgkrmHIgQmyQrQ2XnYigO8PfZwQcEAtcf4cHTA9VN8OmANa1hGp/0vPeQnsCDBt3Bey0zdtXggNAPV3 bob@BobsMac-mini.local
    sudo: ["ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL"]
    groups: sudo
    shell: /bin/bash

cloud-init schema --system
tells me "Error: Invalid schema: user-data"
So I examined /var/lib/cloud/instances/iid-datasource-none/cloud-config.txt file (which I had no idea existed until today) and found
# from 1 files
# part-001

---
growpart:
    mode: 'off'
locale: en_US.UTF-8
preserve_hostname: true
resize_rootfs: false
ssh_pwauth: true
users:
-   gecos: Bob Forehead
    groups: !!set
        adm: null
        cdrom: null
        dip: null
        lxd: null
        plugdev: null
        sudo: null
    lock_passwd: false
    name: msh
    passwd: $6$6GujW5w8MyC5J4w8$WFZmSImu5cg8g0tP1QrA4/E6GVF2iJO2LUAdmrKcJSnJtOFgvComPCqRi6ic61gOz43jBnA4eHULo337qncOQ.
    shell: /bin/bash

I don't even know where the passwd line came from. Another run, probably. Any ideas why ssh authentication fails?

The ttyS0 console is alive but I can't authenticate there either.


I don't even know where the passwd line came from. Another run, probably.

It sounds like the instance was already booted, and you are modifying the user-data a posteriori. If that is the case, the issue is that the users_groups config module only runs once per instance (first boot) and it is not picking up your new user-data.
If this is the case, and you want the new user-data to be process, then one can run cloud-init clean and reboot the instance, but please, be aware that this will fully re-run cloud-init.
If not, consider creating an upstream cloud-init issue, see https://docs.cloud-init.io/en/latest/howto/bugs.html.

When you say "reboot the instance," what do you mean by instance? Thanks.

I mean the guest vm.
